# How to interpret this case of probable overlapping partitions (unallocated drive in Gparted)?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, gparted

I may have played too much with different operating systems and now I'm in trouble.

I'll promise not to do it again, but first please help me put my machine back on track! :))

I had three Linux systems and two Windows on the same laptop! I wanted to get rid of some of them, but before that I decided to test if Windows XP would work on that computer (why? I prefer to have a Windows system at hand but in both Win 7 and 10 the laptop fan is too loud compared to what I want (and have in Linux) and therefore I just wanted to text XP...)

Windows 10 is at the beginning of the drive (sda1), then comes a NTFS larger depo drive without any OS (sda2), then there is an extended partition (sda3) containing the 3 Linux partitions and the Windows 7 partition (detail below).

What I did was: I removed the last Linux (sda8) and there I installed XP and all worked relatively well there - except for the fan, which made me think I should remove XP too etc.

After that, I booted in Live CD and wanted to get rid of some of the Windows partitions: looking at the partitions in Gparted **all the drive looked unallocated**.

[image]

I installed the **boot-repair** tool in the live environment to fix the grub, I used the recommended setting to **remove and reinstall the grub**. I decided to install it on `sda5` (my preferred Linux system) and all looked fine.

After reboot **all the operating systems were available in the boot list, except the last XP partition**.

Also, **in Gparted all the drive is still reported unallocated** - although now all systems except XP are  accessible and working.

Looking [here on How-to Fix Overlapping Partitions](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#overlapping-partitions) I did in Terminal as follows:

```
cip@cip-HP:~ > sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print
[sudo] password for cip: 
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.                                 
cip@cip-HP:~ > sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sda
omitting empty partition (5)

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d2515

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   104859647    52428800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda2       104859648   613181439   254160896    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT 
/dev/sda3       613185596   976766618   181790511+   5  Extended         
/dev/sda4       713537536   799438847    42950656    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       613185598   713537535    50175969   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       799440896   883327614    41943359+  83  Linux
/dev/sda7       883331072   976764927    46716928    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I don't know **how to interpret this**. I see no overlapping, only that sda5 comes before sda4 at the beginning of the extended partition.

I'll add a snapshot with more comments on the partitions:

[image]

What should I do?

UPDATE:

In Windows 7 I have deleted the XP and Windows 10 partitions using Disk Management. That has changed nothing. In Gparted the whole drive is still unallocated. I want to be able to access and use the ex-XP and Win-10 partitions.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward, sda3 is the sum of sda5,sda4,sda6 and sda7, in that order (5 before 4).

You may delete any partition, but deleting sda3 will result in deleting from sda4 to sda7.

Comment: @Archemar - I have removed the XP partition but in Gparted the drive still unallocated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the partition **4**: it is a primary partition contained inside  an extended partition - and that is illegal.

By definition, in a msdos-type partition table, the primary partitions receive numbers from 1 to 4. The fact that the partition *4* is wholly contained inside the extended partition *3* is what is causing these problems.

In the [GParted Wiki](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php) you can read:

> **3.** Primary partitions must not exist within an Extended partition.

Again in [the Gparted wiki](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#overlapping-partitions) but later on, you can read: under the heading **How-to Fix Overlapping Partitions**, you find:

> *Do any of the primary or extended partitions overlap?*
>
> In other words does one partition (numbers 1 to 4) have a start value lower than another partitition (numbers 1 to 4) but also an end value higher than the start of the other partition?

These clearly state that partitions 1-4 are by default *primary*. Hence your extended partition, 3, includes illegally a primary partition.

You can find further confirmation of this very rigid naming scheme [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning).

The strategy to solve this is very easy: rename partition 4 to 8, an allowed number, and then change the partition table to reflect the change. The GParted Wiki page referenced above tells you how to do that; it is sufficiently delicate that I do **not** feel it appropriate to summarize the page content here, you will have to study the process thoroughly lest parts of your disk may vanish into the netherworld.

Also, you will have to modify the files (like `/etc/fstab`) that referred to `sda4` to reflect the change above, wherever partition 4 was used.

Comment: please take a look at my answer which by chance seems to have solved the problem of primary partition inside extended. Would you say that my present configuration is ok? - On the other hand: the primary NTFS partition inside the extended one was there before the problem occurred. Gparted had no problem in seeing the drive before I installed XP in the  partition that was outside the extended one (at the end of the drive). All bad changes were made by installing XP I think.

Comment: Was the older installation of Windows 7 inside a Linux extended partition (created in Gparted) a non-recommended operation? Is it possible that by doing so I had already created a primary partition inside the extended one while no problems manifested at that point? Or maybe  the Windows 7 partition became primary only after I installed XP?

Comment: @cipricus  Yes, creating a primary partition inside an extended partition is an **illegal** operation.  I cannot be positive as to how it came about. I would have thought there be safeguards to prevent such errors in **both** OSes, but clearly this is not so. The most likely culprit is the Windows  installer, which must have the instruments to turn a logical partition into a primary one. But still, I am **not** sure about where the error originated. There is a bug somewhere, but I do not know where it is, sorry about this.

Comment: one more thing: was the report as seen in the question indicating also overlapping partitions or just the "primary inside extended" issue?

Comment: @cipricus You mean in the OP? I do not see any overlap,  just a primary inside an extended.

Comment: I have tried to edit your question to clearly state that at the beginning of your answer, as the initial question was mentioning overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the update to the question:
While Gparted reported all the drive as unallocated in Linux, I have booted in Windows 7, and there all the drive and its partitions were visible in Disk Management. Using Disk Management,I have deleted the Windows XP partition (sda8) which became unallocated space.

I have tried to do the same with the Windows 10 partition (sda1) - but after that the partition was still visible in Disk Management. Unsure whether this was an error and whether Disk Management was the proper tool, I then installed [MiniTool Partition Wizard Free Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) which I had successfully used in the past.

MiniTool Partition Wizard showed not only an unallocated space of 46 GB where the sda8 partition was, but a 85 GB unallocated space in the space of both sad7 and sda8 partitions. **Deleting the XP partition (sda8) had also deleted the sda7 partition** of my (luckily) secondary Linux system.

Then, using MiniTool Partition Wizard, I deleted also the Windows 10 partition (sda1) and created a new Linux ext4 partition out of the 85 GB unallocated space at the end of the drive. Trying to create a new NTFS partition with MiniTool Partition Wizard in the unallocated space at the beginning of the drive, I got a message saying "not enough slots".

I then booted in the one Linux system left, and there now Gparted was seeing all the drive. I extended the large NTFS partition to the left (moving data to the left) in Gparted to get one big NTFS at the beginning of the drive, without any OS, and keeping only Windows 7 and a Linux on this machine. I also kept the separate ext4 partition at the end of the drive.

In terminal I get:

```
cip@cip-HP:~ > sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print
[sudo] password for cip: 
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54505 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 976773168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start       End         Size        Type      File system  Flags
 1      2048s       613181439s  613179392s  primary   ntfs
 2      613185596s  713537535s  100351940s  extended               lba
 5      613185598s  713537535s  100351938s  logical   ext4
 3      713537536s  799438847s  85901312s   primary   ntfs
 4      799438848s  976766975s  177328128s  primary   ext4

cip@cip-HP:~ >  sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d2515

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   613181439   306589696    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       613185596   713537535    50175970    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda3       713537536   799438847    42950656    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       799438848   976766975    88664064   83  Linux
/dev/sda5       613185598   713537535    50175969   83  Linux
```

Now all systems work, and I also don't seem to have the initial problem reported in the other answer: the extended partition (now sda2) doesn't seem to contain any primary partitions anymore. The Windows 7 partition (now sda3) which before had a different number and was a primary partition inside the extended partition, is now seen as a primary partition outside the extended one (which now contains only one logical partition: sda5).

[image]

Comment: The problem with "solutions" like the one above is that they are not easily reproducible. What was the original problem?  The GParted Wiki, http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#disk-unallocated, clearly explains what the symptoms and the root cause of the problem are, undet the heading `Entire Disk Device Shown as Unallocated`.While your solution is a list of steps which may, or may not, be a solution to other guys since you do not have a clear diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - I agree. But that is the best I can do now: report the steps I took. The original problem is that in the question.